# Transforming random vector - checking correctness of solution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function, jacobian, change-of-variable

The task is to calculate two-dimentional probability density of $[X,Y]$ if we know that: 
$$
R \sim U(0,1), \quad \Phi \sim U(0, 2\pi),
$$
$R$ and $\Phi$ are independent and
$$
X := R \cos(\Phi), \quad Y:= R \sin(\Phi).
$$

We have that:
$$
f_{[R, \Phi]}(r, \phi) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(r) \frac{1}{2 \pi} \mathbf{1}_{[0,2\pi]}(\phi)
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
X = R \cos(\Phi) \\
Y = R \sin(\Phi)
\end{cases}
\quad
\Rightarrow
\quad
\begin{cases}
\Phi = \arcsin \Big{(}  \frac{Y}{ \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2} }   \Big{)}\\
R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
|J| = R = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}
$$

$$
g_{[X,Y]}(x,y) = f( \Phi(x,y), R(x,y)  ) |J| = 
$$

$$
\mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}\Big{(} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \Big{)} \frac{1}{2 \pi} \mathbf{1}_{[0, 2\pi]} \Big{(} \arcsin \Big{(} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  \Big{)}\Big{)} \sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$

Is this solution correct so far?

Now I have a problem solving:

$$
\begin{cases}
0 \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \le 1  \\
0 \le \arcsin \Big{(} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}  \Big{)} \le 2\pi
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jacobian determinant is with respect to $(x,y)$, so it should be

$$J=J\left(\frac{r,\phi}{x,y}\right)=\frac1{J\left(\frac{x,y}{r,\phi}\right)}=\frac1r=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

Note that $$0<r<1\implies r^2<1\implies x^2+y^2<1$$

And $$0<\phi<2\pi\implies \tan\phi=\frac{y}{x}\in \mathbb R\implies (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2$$

So joint density of $(X,Y)$ is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{R,\Phi}(r,\phi)|J|=\cdots$$

Comment: Oh, you are of course right :) Thanks!